# Random Image on Refresh

Tags: javascript, hta

I need some help to fix an error on this code:

```
var image = new Array ();
image[0] = "http://placehold.it/20";
image[1] = "http://placehold.it/30";
image[2] = "http://placehold.it/40";
image[3] = "http://placehold.it/50";
var size = image.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

$('#random').attr('src',image[x]);
```

The error I get when I run the HTA(Hyper Text Application) is:
Line: 46
Error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object.
Line 46 is this line:

```
$('#random').attr('src',image[x]);
```

The link to the question that I found this code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SvswX/9/)

**EDIT**

Here is the code for my whole program [here](http://pastebin.com/rSZ6MU4V)

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you include jquery?

Comment: @hicurin No I haven't, to be honest with you, i haven't learned jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jquery at the top of your page and in head tab:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Try it again:

```
$(function(){

    var image = new Array ();
    image[0] = "http://placehold.it/20";
    image[1] = "http://placehold.it/30";
    image[2] = "http://placehold.it/40";
    image[3] = "http://placehold.it/50";
    var size = image.length
    var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

    $('#random').attr('src',image[x]);

})
```

Comment: I have checked jsfiddle and it works fine. Could you share your page?

Comment: Your url is invalid //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js. So let use it "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" with "http:"

Comment: Let try use <img id="random"/> instead of <img id='random'/>

Comment: Really fun! Try so much haha

Answer (score 4):

Add Jquery library in your file `<head>` block

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
    var image = new Array ();
    image[0] = "http://placehold.it/20";
    image[1] = "http://placehold.it/30";
    image[2] = "http://placehold.it/40";
    image[3] = "http://placehold.it/50";
    var size = image.length
    var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

    $('#random').attr('src',image[x]);
    });
   </script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SvswX/11/)

Comment: That solves half of the problem, now when I launch the program the screen goes white...

Comment: That solves the other half of the problem, the program launches, but  I get this error:
Line: 20
Error: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object
Here is the line:
 $('#random').attr('src',image[x]);

Comment: adding jquery will stop the $ undefined error, there are other errors in your code, see my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

try this one.. hope it's help

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
    var image = new Array ();
    image[0] = "http://placehold.it/20";
    image[1] = "http://placehold.it/30";
    image[2] = "http://placehold.it/40";
    image[3] = "http://placehold.it/50";
    var size = image.length
    var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

    $('#random').attr('src',image[x]);
    });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code, Here's a working example...

Make sure [jQuery is included on your page](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp)

```
$(document).ready({

   // jQuery has now loaded on the page

   var image = [];
   image[0] = "http://placehold.it/20";
   image[1] = "http://placehold.it/30";
   image[2] = "http://placehold.it/40";
   image[3] = "http://placehold.it/50";

   var src = image[Math.floor(Math.random() * image.length)];

   $('#random').attr('src',src);

});
```

[link to example](http://codepen.io/Bloodylyons/pen/Dxual)